# Spring Boot Rest API with JWT authentication

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, authentication

I have a Spring Boot Rest API which I will authenticate against and return a JWT token for further API authorization.

My problem is, that the POST request to my auth endpoint doesn't return the JWT Token, therefore I think my problem is inside the authentication workflow. More specific: it never reaches the successfulAuthentication method of the JWTAuthenticationFilter.

A test user is created on startup, credentials are correct (checked the pass encoding).

I have the following classes:

Rest API \

├── JWTAuthenticationFilter

├── SecurityConfiguration

├── UserDetailsServiceImpl

My SecurityConfig where I add the filters and enable the BCrypt password encoder:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = AccountRepo.class)
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true, prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }   

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()

            // add filters
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))

            // don't create session
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()

            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(authenticationUrl).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()

            .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean(name="passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }

}
```

JWTAuthenticationFilter:

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter { 

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            AuthenticationRequest creds = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), AuthenticationRequest.class);

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getEmail(),
                            creds.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>())
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .setExpiration(Date.from(OffsetDateTime.now().plusMinutes(EXPIRATION_TIME).toInstant()))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET.getBytes())
                .compact();
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }
}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl, where I look up the user return the user with authorities:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService service;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        VAccount account = service.getAccountByEmail(email);
        if(account == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("no user found with email '" + email + "'");
        }

        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        for (VRole role : account.getRoles()){
            System.out.println(role.getName().toString());
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().toString()));
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(account.getEmail(), account.getPassHash(), grantedAuthorities);
    }

}
```

Does anyone see any problems with that auth flow or where it might break?

Comment: I don't understand any of this. The purpose of JWT is to embed a credential and authorizations together in a transparent and independently verifiable token. i.e. you have all the information you need _inside_ the token. I don't really understand why you need to get accounts by email and then loop over some roles.

Comment: So based on your comment would it be plausible if I authenticate the user in the JWTAuthenticationFilter and return the JWT afterwards?

Comment: You should authenticate **and** authorise your user _somewhere else_. Some trusted authn and authz server would process the authentication. Your service then just receives the JWT and, because it knows the secret, can validate the token and extract the authorizations. Your current use is no different to a session cookie and has absolutely not benefit. Just use a session cookie.

Comment: Sessions and session cookies are not stateless, but a Rest API is. So why don't evolve to a real stateless Rest API with JWT token? But aside from this philosophic question, do you have any hint why the Rest API doesn't return the token?